# Angular Js css not working for ng repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi Here is the css inside browser it working perfectly but using external css not working why ?

```
<!-- Showing ng-repeat Demo [START] -->
<table width="900px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Sr No.</th>
      <th>Plate</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Entrance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Iterating over the cars -->
    <tr data-ng-repeat="car in cars" data-ng-class="{ 'firstClass' : $first , 'lastClass' : $last , 'middleClass' : $middle, 'selected' : car.selected }">
      <!-- Showing the car's plate -->
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="car.selected"/></td>
      <td><span data-ng-bind="$index"></span><span data-ng-bind="$first"></span><span data-ng-bind="$last"></span><span data-ng-bind="$middle"></span></td>
      <td><span data-ng-bind="car.plate"></span></td>
      <td><span data-ng-bind="car.color" data-ng-style="{color: car.color}"></span></td>
      <td><span data-ng-bind="car.entrance"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .firstClass{
        background: #84471A;
        color:black;
    }

    .lastClass{
        background: #84471A;
        color:black;
    }

    .middleClass{
        background: #D79B6F;
        color:black;      
    }

    .selected{
        background: cyan;
        color:black;
    }
</style>
```

Please explain why ? I am not getting it properlywhen running form external css. don't know why ? Please suggest.

Comment: Try putting `!important` in external CSS for all the elements. And I hope you are not putting `<style type="text/css">` in external CSS.

Comment: Where do you store / load the external CSS?

Comment: have you added external css reference in your html page?